# Relational database table that may or may not have relationship with other table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relational-database

In my rails application, there are two tables `Plan` and `Subscription`. `Plan` table has `has_many` with `Subscription` and `Subscription` has `belongs_to` with `Plan`.

I want to create a `Subscription` that will not belong to a `Plan`. Can I create `Subscription` without specifying the `plan_id`? Or, should I use `has_many_through`?

Comment: Which version of rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a `Subscription` without specifying a `Plan`. If you are on Rails 5, you will need to do:

```
belongs_to :plan, optional: true
```

According to the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference):

> If you set the :optional option to true, then the presence of the associated object won't be validated. By default, this option is set to false.

Comment: Will it affect the index created in `Subscription` model for `Plan`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "will it affect"? Will it edit the index? No. Will it degrade the performance of the index? No. Something else?

Answer (score 1):

I personnally dont really like the default required belongs_to in rails 5. You can add this line in application.rb. You will have to add a validation when you want a belongs_to to be required.

```
config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false
```